# How to write the output of `:au` in a file

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I am debugging a plugin, and to do so saving the output of `au` into either a file or a temporary buffer would help immensely. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:redir > filename
:autocmd
:redir END
```

See `:help :redir`.